# sql server stored procedure sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
USE [all_things]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getThingsByType]
    @thingid int,
    @typeid int
AS

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * from items'

IF @thingid IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' where thingid = @thingid'
END

IF @typeid IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' and TypeID = @typeid'
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@thingid int,@typeid int',@thingid=@thingid,@typeid=@typeid;
```

Test cases:

1. When I run it with the `thingid` is `null` and `typeid` is `null`, I get all results which is perfect.
2. When the `thingid` is supplied and the `typeid` is `null`, the results are ok
3. Here is where, the results are not good: `thingid` is `null` and `typeid` is supplied. Everything is being returned.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: imho, if thingid is null and not typeid you have a malformed query looking `select * from items and TypeID = @typeid`.

Comment: I wasn't seeing that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @tschmit007, I fixed it.

```
USE [all_things]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getThingsByType]
    @thingid int,
    @typeid int
AS

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * from items'

IF @thingid IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' where thingid = @thingid'
END

IF @typeid IS NOT NULL AND @thingid IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' and TypeID = @typeid'
END

IF @typeid IS NOT NULL AND @thingid IS NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' where TypeID = @typeid'
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@thingid int,@typeid int',@thingid=@thingid,@typeid=@typeid;
```